# Storing bottle conditioned beers and carbonation

Tags: carbonation, temperature, bottle-conditioning, storage

I store all my beer at 55°F(12.7°C). Do I need to worry about the beers that are bottle conditioned not being carbonated, or not being at the proper carbonation level? Should they already be carbonated when I purchase them? The main reason for this question is the issues Lost Abbey and the Bruery were having with carbonation. A friend suggested I let all my Lost Abbey stuff sit around 70°F (21°C) and shake it up a bit every once in a while for a few months. Is this a good suggestion?

Comment: Relevant http://brewadvice.com/questions/35/how-to-store-beer/36#36

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When bottle conditioned beers leave the brewery they are already at the proper CO2 levels, unless otherwise specified.

It's better to store beer at a cooler temperature.  The 3 things that destroy beer are light, heat, and oxygen.

Don't shake your beers, you will re-suspend everything that has dropped out over time.

Answer (score 1):

Without a major increase in heat, I can't see how your bottle conditioned beer would get much better or worse.  Isn't that the purpose of conditioning?

Answer (score 0):

What style beers are they?  Lost Abbey and The Bruery (both great breweries) have a lot of quads and unique styles that aren't going to be as carbonated as a pilsner or IPA.

I wouldn't shake it up right before drinking. Let the bottles sit right before opening then gently pour so you don't get all the yeast into your glass.